# Parse : Including Related Objects in Queries <PHP>

Tags: php, parsing, parse-platform, laravel-5

I have _Installation and Swipt_User classes in parse, the installation has UserR, which related to Swipt_User table as in the pic :

[image]

I have this query :

```
$query = new ParseQuery("_Installation");
$query->includeKey("Swipt_User");
$installations = $query->find(true);
```

included the object related to installation which is Swipt_User, but when i try to get the object in foreach, it didn't get it as below and returned  as null

```
foreach ($installations as $key => $installation) {
    $user = $installation->get('Swipt_User');
}
```

Any help ? .. please

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name of the column, not the name of the related table (group), when using `include`.

Your code needs to be:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("_Installation");
$query->includeKey("userR");
$installations = $query->find(true);
```